# std::this_thread::get_id() vs passing ID

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the difference between these two codes?
What is the best / fastest way.
Trying to make my own WM_TIMER thread.

1st: timerThreadProc

with get_id()

```
DWORD WINAPI timerThreadProc(DWORD dwMilliseconds)
{
    while (!bExit)
    {
        if (std::this_thread::get_id() == hTimer1Thread.get_id())
        {
            // do what ever
            Beep(10000, 100);
        }

        if (std::this_thread::get_id() == hTimer2Thread.get_id())
        {
            // do what ever
            Beep(1000, 100);
        }

        Sleep(dwMilliseconds);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

2nd: timerThreadProc

without get_id()

```
#define TIMER1 1
#define TIMER2 2
DWORD WINAPI timerThreadProc(UINT ID, DWORD dwMilliseconds)
{
    while (!bExit)
    {
        if (ID == TIMER1)
        {
            // do what ever
            Beep(10000, 100);
        }

        if (ID == TIMER2)
        {
            // do what ever
            Beep(1000, 100);
        }

        Sleep(dwMilliseconds);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example uses the facilities in the C++ library to determine whether the current running thread is `hTimer1Thread`'s thread, or `hTimer2Thread`'s thread.

The second example performs a comparable task by comparing its parameter against predefined constants that, presumably, refer to the same two threads.

This is, pretty much, as you've summarized; but what's left unmentioned here is that the second approach must also necessitate some additional support, of some kind, outside of the shown code, to keep track of what the executing thread represents, and to map that to one of the two predefined constants. You have to presume this, based on the shown implementation.

So, it is not really possible to determine here what's the "best/fastest" way.

What's "fastest" depends heavily on the internal details of the C++ library implementation. Whether `get_id()`, for a `this_thread`, or some arbitrary thread, is inlined, for example, and how efficient it is. As compared to however efficient would be additional, out of band, approach used in the second example.

What's "best" also depends on the rest of the application. Depending on the details of the application's requirements, and behavior, it's possible that the first approach will work slightly better. It's also possible that the second approach will work slightly better.

But, what's more likely is that given modern, fast CPUs and modern, intelligent, optimizing compilers, it makes no measurable difference either way, and this is reduced solely to the style and the maintainability of the overall code.

Which means that you, yourself, will be the best person to answer this question, since you know more about this specific application than anyone else on stackoverflow.com